# In django-guardian, how can I get all objects user has any permissions for

Tags: django, django-guardian

In django-guardian, how can I get all objects user has any permission for (through groups as well). There is a [shortcut to get all users having any permission over an object](https://pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-users-with-perms), but I am searching for all objects a given user has any permission over.

Answer (score 3):

[get_objects_for_user()](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-objects-for-user)

```
>>> from guardian.shortcuts import get_objects_for_user
>>> joe = User.objects.get(username='joe')
>>> get_objects_for_user(joe, 'auth.change_group')
[]

>>> from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm
>>> group = Group.objects.create('some group')
>>> assign_perm('auth.change_group', joe, group)
>>> get_objects_for_user(joe, 'auth.change_group')
[<Group some group>]
```

For **any** permission you could type the codenames in a list yourself, or use [get_perms_for_model()](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-perms-for-model).

```
>>> group_perms = [perm.codename for perm in get_perms_for_model(Group)]
>>> get_objects_for_user(joe, group_perms, klass=Group, any_perm=True)
[<Group some group>]
```

Comment: Based on `get_objects_for_user` code, this seems quite inefficient?

Comment: @Mitar well... it's pretty complex due to all the guessing that the function does with the content type, etc. Also the permissions are split into 2 tables for users and groups and it also needs the ContentType so it can't be done without several queries. I doubt you can improve the queries much without resorting to raw SQL.

Comment: You can, I made a pull request: https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian/pull/247 (Instead of making one query to list permissions and then limit objects to those, you just remove the filter on permissions.)